# .NET Stateless multiple guards, different states, same trigger

Tags: c#, stateless-state-machine

I feel like I've read every example of the [stateless](https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless) library I could find and haven't found out either why I can't do what I want, or what I should do instead.

Here's an extremely rudimentary example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

In this example, my state machine has 3 possible states, and two events/triggers:

```
enum MyStates
{
    WaitingForData,
    RequestingNewData,
    Complete
}


enum MyTriggers
{
    Initialized,
    NewDataArrived
}
```

we always start in `WaitingForData` and kick off initialized event right away:

```
var sm = new StateMachine<MyStates, MyTriggers>(MyStates.WaitingForData);

sm.Configure(MyStates.WaitingForData)
    .PermitIf(MyTriggers.Initialized, MyStates.RequestingNewData, 
        () => IsDataPresent() && !IsDataUpToDate())
    .PermitIf(MyTriggers.Initialized, MyStates.Complete, 
        () => IsDataPresent() && IsDataUpToDate());

sm.Configure(MyStates.RequestingNewData)
    .OnEntryAsync(() =>
    {
        dataService.RequestNewDataAsync().Completed(task =>
        {
            sm.FireAsync(MyTriggers.NewDataArrived);
        });
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    })
    .Permit(MyTriggers.NewDataArrived, MyStates.Complete);


await sm.FireAsync(MyTriggers.Initialized);
```

(you can ignore the poor use of async/TaskCompleted in the OnEntry function, that's just to help illustrate the example)

The goal here is to wait in `WaitingForData` until the data is present.  Once it's present, if the present data is up to date, we can immediately proceed to complete, otherwise, we need to proceed to `RequestingNewData` where we'll request new data and then transition to complete.

However, if the data is *not* present when we fire `Initialized` at the start, we get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Trigger 'Initialized' is valid for transition from state 'WaitingForData' but a guard conditions are not met. Guard descriptions: 'Function'.'
```

The stateless docs clearly state:

> Guard clauses within a state must be mutually exclusive (multiple guard clauses cannot be valid at the same time.)

Which makes total sense, but these two guard clauses can never be valid at the same time, they can however both be `False` at the same time, which I would hope would leave the SM stuck in `WaitingForData`, but instead I get an error.

A possible solution I've come up with is to create a new transitionary state `CheckingIfDataIsUpToDate` or something after waiting for data, but then I also need an additional trigger like `DataChecked` and the complexity of the state machine goes way up.

What is the best way to accomplish what I'm aiming for?

Comment: I'm not familiar with "stateless", but perhaps the intent is that you should have a transition back to the same state as a fallback if none of the guard conditions are met?

Comment: I haven't checked, but I think this can be handled with a InternalTransitionIf() that handles Initialized when data isn't ready.
The problem you have to deal with is that you have four different combinations of your guard functions, but only handle two of them.